# Is there a way to create a URL that routes to various YouTube streaming URLs?

Tags: url, youtube

My church streams our weekly service on YouTube since we can’t be there in person. Almost every week, the streaming link goes down and we have to create a new link and send it out to everyone via text message. The problem is that a lot of people miss the text and can’t find the new YouTube link.

Is it possible to create a static URL that everyone can have, and all we would have to do is map the new YouTube streaming link to the static URL on the backend? That way, I’m hoping the viewer can just press the refresh button and auto-connect to the new YouTube streaming URL.

I am not tech savvy, but trying to learn based on the recent need for it. If you could dumb down any explanation, that would be appreciated. Thank you for your time!